# Private network: Using geth to mine for parity nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, parity

I want to set up a private Ethereum network using a parity client. Ideally, I want to resemble the "real" Ethereum network as close as possible. Thus, I want to set up a proof of work network. For that, I used the chain configuration below for Parity. I now want to mine on this private chain, but with a cpu miner. I have found only Geth being capable of doing that. However, when I attach to the parity node running the private chain, I can not use the `miner.start()` command.

How can I use a geth node to mine for a parity node?

Parity node configuration:

```
{
"name": "CrossClient",
"dataDir": "CrossClient",
"engine": {
    "Ethash": {
        "params": {
            "minimumDifficulty": "0x020000",
            "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x0800",
            "durationLimit": "0x0d",
            "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
            "homesteadTransition": 0,
            "eip150Transition": 0,
            "eip160Transition": 10,
            "eip161abcTransition": 10,
            "eip161dTransition": 10
        }
    }
},
"params": {
    "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400",
    "registrar": "0x81a4b044831c4f12ba601adb9274516939e9b8a2",
    "eip155Transition": 10,
    "accountStartNonce": "0x0",
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
    "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
    "networkID" : "0x539"
},
"genesis": {
    "seal": {
        "ethereum": {
            "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
            "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "difficulty": "0x10000",
    "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x3535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535",
    "gasLimit": "0x1000000"
},
"accounts": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "0", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "0", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "0", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "nonce": "0", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can run miner.start() on your Geth node, if you enable this rpc module at geth's start.

Example :

```
geth --networkid=3 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,admin,personal,miner,debug" --etherbase 0xe78150FaCD36E8EB00291e251424a0515AA1FF05
```

This "miner" module is not available in Parity as there is not embedded miner for it (unless you configure an external GPU miner linked to Parity).